# How to fix cannot find symbol here

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BankAccount {
    private static double INT_RATE = 4.6;

    private int accNo;
    // Stores Client Name
    private String accName;
    // Stores balance of the account
    private double balance;
    // Store OverDraft Limit
   private double clientodLimit;
    // Store the date that teh account was opened
    private String opened;
    // Store a list of Clienttotaltransactions
    private ArrayList Clienttotaltransactions;
   private Date opened;

    // DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    // Set attributes to default values that we specify 
    public BankAccount()
    {
        accNo = 0;
        accName = "Empty";
        balance = 0.0;
        clientodLimit = 0;
        opened = new Date();
        Clienttotaltransactions = new ArrayList();
        Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],0.0,0.0));
    }

    // COPY CONSTRUCTOR
    public BankAccount(BankAccount a)
    {
        accNo = a.accNo;
        accName = a.accName;
        balance = a.balance;
        clientodLimit = a.clientodLimit;
        opened = new Date(a.opened);
        Clienttotaltransactions = new ArrayList(a.Clienttotaltransactions);
    }





    public BankAccount(int no)
    {
        accNo = no;
        accName = "Empty";
        balance = 0.0;
        clientodLimit = 0;
        opened = new Date();
        Clienttotaltransactions = new ArrayList();
        Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],0.0,0.0));
    }


    public BankAccount(int no, String name, double bal)
    {
        accNo = no;
        accName = name;
        balance = bal;
        clientodLimit = 0;
        opened = new Date();
        Clienttotaltransactions = new ArrayList();
        Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],bal,bal));
    }

    // clone method 
    public Object clone()
    {
        BankAccount x = new BankAccount();
        x.accNo = accNo;
        x.accName = accName;
        x.balance = balance;
        x.clientodLimit = clientodLimit;
        x.opened = new Date(opened);
        x.Clienttotaltransactions = new ArrayList(Clienttotaltransactions);
        return x;
    }

    // equals method
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        return accNo == ((BankAccount)other).accNo;
    }

    // toString() method - ALWAYS takes the form  public String toString()
    // Returns a string representation of the object
    public String toString()
    {
        return accNo+": "+accName+": "+balance;
    }


    // RELEVANT ACCESSOR Methods
    public void setAccName(String name)
    {
        accName = name;
    }

    public void setclientodLimit(double newLimit)
    {
        clientodLimit = newLimit;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public String getAccName()
    {
        return accName;
    }

    public int getAccNo()
    {
        return accNo;
    }

    public static void ClientsetINT_RATE(double newIR)
    {
        INT_RATE = newIR;
    }

    public static double getINT_RATE()
    {
        return INT_RATE;
    }
        public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance + amount;
        Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[0],amount,balance));
    }


    public boolean withdraw(double widamount)
    {
        boolean valid = false;
        if (checkWithdraw(widamount))
        {
            balance = balance - widamount;
            valid = true;
            Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[1],-widamount,balance));
        }
        return valid;
    }


    public void addInterestcalcu()
    {
        double interest = 0;
        interest = balance*(INT_RATE/100);
        deposit(interest);
    }

        private boolean checkWithdraw(double amount)
    {
        boolean valid = true;
        if((balance-amount) < clientodLimit)
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

        public String createStatement()
    {
        // create a temporary string to hold the whole statement
        String state = "";

        // create a reference (pointer) to a Trans object 
        // called temp 
        Trans temp;



        for(int i=0; i < Clienttotaltransactions.size(); i++)
        {
            temp = (Trans)Clienttotaltransactions.get(i);
            state = state+"\n"+temp.toString();
        }
        return state;
    }

}
```

I have some errors below, and I don't know how to fix them.

> BankAccount.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
>          private Date opened;
>                  ^
>         symbol:   class Date
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
>             opened = new Date();
>                          ^
>         symbol:   class Date
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],0.0,0.0));
>                                             ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],0.0,0.0));
>                                                   ^
>         symbol:   variable Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
>             opened = new Date(a.opened);
>                          ^
>         symbol:   class Date
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
>             opened = new Date();
>                          ^
>         symbol:   class Date
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],0.0,0.0));
>                                             ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],0.0,0.0));
>                                                   ^
>         symbol:   variable Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
>             opened = new Date();
>                          ^
>         symbol:   class Date
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],bal,bal));
>                                             ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[4],bal,bal));
>                                                   ^
>         symbol:   variable Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
>             x.opened = new Date(opened);
>                            ^
>         symbol:   class Date
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[0],amount,balance));
>                                             ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
>             Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[0],amount,balance));
>                                                   ^
>         symbol:   variable Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
>                 Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[1],-widamount,balance));
>                                                 ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
>                 Clienttotaltransactions.add(new Trans(Trans.TRANSTYPE[1],-widamount,balance));
>                                                       ^
>         symbol:   variable Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:182: error: cannot find symbol
>             Trans temp;
>             ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       BankAccount.java:188: error: cannot find symbol
>                 temp = (Trans)Clienttotaltransactions.get(i);
>                         ^
>         symbol:   class Trans
>         location: class BankAccount
>       Note: BankAccount.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>       18 errors

So the error comes from opened, Date and Trans. I try to add some thing to valueable those words, but it doesn't work. : (
It need more detils, but I don't have more.

Comment: what and where is the class trans?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the  properly package for the [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class

```
java.util.Date
```

## do the same for the class Trans and all others that show the same error cause....

Comment: What about the rest?

Comment: is not intuitive enough to solve similar issues ????

Comment: You're asking me or OP? With a question like this I think you need to spoon-feed a bit more.

Comment: It's not slove problems@ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa